# How to insert variables in inline CSS rules with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, inline-styles

I am calculating the x variable earlier in the code and i want to insert that variable value in the inline style of the div, but it doesn't work, though it works perfectly if i insert constant like "100px".

```
var x;  
document.getElementById("block").style.position = "fixed";  
document.getElementById("block").style.left = x;
```

Note: i want to get it working without using jquery because i am using only a couple of scripts on the website and it is useless to link a big library in my case.

Comment: Something to consider: it _may_ be useless to link a "big" library like jQuery only _if_ you host it yourself. You can use the jQuery CDN or Google's CDN to do the heavy lifting for you on the client side. jQuery gives you a tremendous development advantage over raw JavaScript. That's why it was created in the first place. Also, jQuery is **pure JavaScript**.

Comment: What is `x`? A number? A string?

Comment: So long as you've got an appropriate value for `x` what you've written should work (albeit I'd retrieve the element once, and use a cached variable to access it again). So, what happens, or doesn't happen, that goes against your expectations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so I can't post comments yet but I've run into a similar problem before.

Without any additional code I can make an assumption that x is the calculated value and it is a number. It is invalid css to insert just a number into left thus you must append a unit to it before assign it to the property:

`document.getElementById("block").style.left = x + 'px';`

If that fixes your problem, then great! Otherwise please post how you calculate x between `var x;` to the assignment of x.

Answer (score 10):

If you came here looking how to set [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) in the inline style, here you go:

```
element.style.setProperty("--my-var", jsVar + 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
var xx = 100
document.getElementById("block").style.width = xx+'px';
```